# Im getting an error while running elastic search

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, spyder

I tried installing and running elastic search.Its showing error on my PC but it is working on my friend's PC.I tried uninstalling elastic search and resinstalled it. But no success.

```
def searchIndex(keyword="xxx", info_list = [],index_name="umls", doc_type="keywords"):
    baseQuery = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "text": keyword
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    results = es.search(index=index_name,doc_type=doc_type, body=baseQuery)
```

return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)

TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'

Comment: What is the version of elasticsearch and python library?

Comment: elastic search-6.7.2. I also tried the latest version-7.2.0
spyder-(python)3.7

Comment: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/2204

Comment: @LinSel I tried all the posts in that page but no results.